# Error Message when plotting ROC of H2O Model Object in R

Tags: r, h2o, roc

Trying to plot ROC curve for H2O Model Object in R, however, I keep receiving the following error message:

"Error in as.double(y) : 
  cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'"

My code is as follows:

`drf1 <- h2o.randomForest(x=x,y=y,training_frame = train,validation_frame = valid, nfolds = nfolds, fold_assignment = "Modulo",keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE,seed = 1)`

`plot((h2o.performance(drf1,valid = T)), type = "roc")`

I followed suggestions found here: [How to directly plot ROC of h2o model object in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44034944/how-to-directly-plot-roc-of-h2o-model-object-in-r)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your data using `dput(df)`?

Answer (score 1):

From the error, I think your response variable is not binary. You can change your response variable to factor before putting it into model. i.e.

```
df$y <- as.factor(df$y)
```

*"ROC is a graphical plot that illustrates the diagnostic ability of a **binary classifier** system as its discrimination threshold is varied".*

source:
[ROC wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic)